# Arduino Nano PWM interferes SERVO

Tags: arduino, noise, pwm, servo, arduino-nano

I tried to make soap - bubble robot for my kid. It is simple. There is lever on servo that soak the ring in soapwater and place in front of fan. Problem is that when I activate PWM servo begin to misbehave (shaking, tremble go to 0 position) although they don't run at the same time. Seems that there is some noise in servo pin during PWM.

```
  #include <Servo.h>
  Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
  #define MOTOR_PIN 11 
  int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

  void setup() {
    myservo.attach(4);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MOTOR_PIN, OUTPUT);

  }

  void loop() {
    analogWrite(MOTOR_PIN,0);
    delay(100);
    for (pos = 30; pos <= 120; pos += 1) { 
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);              
      delay(10);                      
    }

     for (pos = 120; pos >= 30; pos -= 1) { 
      myservo.write(pos);              
      delay(10);                      
    } 

      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
      delay(200);                       
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
      delay(150);                       
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
      delay(150); 

      analogWrite(MOTOR_PIN, 400);

      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
      delay(150);      
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
      delay(150);                       
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  
      delay(150);      
      delay (3000);

  }
```

[Image of protoboard servo and pwm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBy9L.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I removed that answer.  I had misread the code somehow and thought you were using pin 10.  In that case, how are you powering this project?  Where is the servo getting power from?  Where is the fan motor getting it's power?  How is that power source connected to the Arduino?

Comment: Are you sure that your servo is able to pull enough current? I hope you are not powering any of them from Arduino directly. Either case, it seems like when the fan is running, servo is starving of current. Make sure that your power source can provide enough current for both. Even though servo is not working, it still pulls some current to stay in position, especially under load.

Comment: Thanks guys. As you can see in the picture, I pull all power from single 18650 battery. Servo and fan pwm mosfet module are directly attached to it, as well as arduino nano o voltage step up module. Now I think that it makes sense to put servo or fan on separate battery.  I will let you know about outcome.

Comment: Nop, I even put 3 different batteries (mutual ground) for the arduino, fan and servo still shaking. And even a 1000micrF capacitor to reduce pvm noise (honestly, it's blind shoot).

Comment: Tried 2 different servos, changed to Aurduino Mini pro 328p 5v. Identical oucome. :(